# How many numbers in range satisfy a condition

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I have a digit dynamic programming problem that I am stuck on.

Let x be a number that has no adjacent digits such that `abs(x[i] - x[i+1]) <= 1`, that is if you take the absolute value of the difference of any two adjacent digits of x, you get a number that is larger than 1. For example, digits 1 and 2 can't be adjacent, as can't 5 and 5.

The goal is to count how many numbers x are in the range [A,B]. I know this is a [digit dynamic programming](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/digit-dp-introduction/) problem but I don't know what is wrong with my attempt.

Example:
For input: 110 130, the output should be 1 (because only 130 satisfies the condition). My code correctly outputs 1 but fails on other inputs.

Here is my attempt. I know I need to add memoization but I would like to get the algorithm right before.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int dp[5001][10][2];
const int MOD = 10000;

int count(vector<int> &digits, int idx, int digit_before, int less, int leading_zero) {
    if (idx == digits.size()) return 1;

    if (dp[idx][digit_before][leading_zero] != -1 && less)
        return dp[idx][digit_before][leading_zero];

    int cnt = 0;
    int k = less ? 9 : digits[idx];

    for (int i = 0; i <= k; i++) {
        int zero = (i == 0) ? leading_zero : 0;
        int new_less = (i == k) ? less : 1;
        if (!leading_zero && abs(digit_before - i) <= 1) continue;
        cnt += count(digits, idx + 1, i, new_less, zero);
        cnt %= MOD;
    }

    if (less) {
        dp[idx][digit_before][leading_zero] = cnt;
    }

    return cnt;
}

int main() {
    memset(dp, -1, sizeof(dp));

    string a, b;
    cin >> a >> b;

    vector<int> a_digits{};
    for (auto i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        a_digits.push_back(a[i] - '0');
    }

    vector<int> b_digits{};
    for (auto i = 0; i < b.size(); i++) {
        b_digits.push_back(b[i] - '0');
    }

    auto i = a_digits.size() - 1;
    for (; a_digits[i] == 0; i--);
    a_digits[i]--;

    cout << (count(b_digits, 0, 0, 0, 1) - count(a_digits, 0, 0, 0, 1)) % MOD;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: on which inputs does it fail?

Comment: @juvian I'm not sure because the evaluator doesn't show the inputs, it just says that the output is incorrect :(. I'm guessing it fails on larger inputs because it seems to work fine for up to 3 digits...

Comment: problem link? Could it be that its taking too long? I tested up to 100000 and seems to give the right result

Comment: @juvian it's a private evaluator, takes about 800ms on all the failed cases and it usually signals when the time limit is exceeded (I think the upper limit is 1s), so that's not it :/

Comment: Are you sure the range is inclusive on both sides? How big can the numbers be?

Comment: @juvian I've just realized that the numbers can be as big as 10^(5000), which means that I have to use a string to load the numbers, but now I go over the time limit

Comment: Well If the numbers can go as high as that then the count will also be very big, so counting each solution 1 by 1 would be too slow. Probably need another algorithm with a kind of formula

Comment: @juvian Yeah, I forgot to mention I have to give the answer modulo 10000, I have edited the main post with what I have now. I've tested it and it seems to run fast but still wrong output :/. I suspect I have to change the modulo operations slightly because it sometimes prints out a negative number which is obviously nonsense.

Comment: For no negative number do (count(b_digits, 0, 0, 0, 1) - count(a_digits, 0, 0, 0, 1) + MOD) % MOD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several bugs in you code. For example:

```
// try for a_digits = {1,0,0,0};
auto i = a_digits.size() - 1;
for (; a_digits[i] == 0; i--);
a_digits[i]--;
```

Your `dp[idx][digit_before][leading_zero]` state is incorrect. it should be `dp[idx][digit_before][leading_zero][less]`, because `int k = less ? 9 : digits[idx];` depends on `less`.

Also you have to set `memset(dp, -1, sizeof(dp));` every time before calling `count(vector<int> &digits, int idx, int digit_before, int less, int leading_zero)` because `vector<int> &digits` could be different.

Fixed code is given below:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int dp[5001][10][2][2];
const int MOD = 10000;

int count(vector<int> &digits, int idx, int digit_before, int less, int leading_zero) {
    if (idx == digits.size()) return 1;

    if (dp[idx][digit_before][leading_zero][less] != -1)
        return dp[idx][digit_before][leading_zero][less];

    int cnt = 0;
    int k = less ? 9 : digits[idx];

    for (int i = 0; i <= k; i++) {
        int zero = (i == 0) ? leading_zero : 0;
        int new_less = (i == k) ? less : 1;
        if (!leading_zero && abs(digit_before - i) <= 1) continue;
        cnt += count(digits, idx + 1, i, new_less, zero);
        cnt %= MOD;
    }

    dp[idx][digit_before][leading_zero][less] = cnt;

    return cnt;
}

int main() {
    string a, b;
    cin >> a >> b;

    vector<int> a_digits{};
    for (auto i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        a_digits.push_back(a[i] - '0');
    }

    vector<int> b_digits{};
    for (auto i = 0; i < b.size(); i++) {
        b_digits.push_back(b[i] - '0');
    }

    auto i = a_digits.size() - 1;
    for (; a_digits[i] == 0; i--);
    a_digits[i]--;
    if(a_digits[i] == 0) {
        i++;
        for(; i <= a_digits.size(); i++) {
            a_digits[i] = 9;
        }
    }

    memset(dp, -1, sizeof(dp));
    int cnt1 = count(b_digits, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    memset(dp, -1, sizeof(dp));
    int cnt2 = count(a_digits, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    cout << ( cnt1 - cnt2 + MOD ) % MOD;

    return 0;
}
```